# Threading a class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I'm currently doing a program in python using an UI done in Qt. This UI consists of programming some data and sending them after a click of a button every 200ms. My problem is that if I do this in my main class, the program completely crashes (freeze) so I have to do this in another class or function. After a bit of research, I came across threading, I don't know if it's the right solution for me but it's supposed to run my class in another thread(in the background) until I press the stop button without making my main window crash. The second class needs to have a loop until i press the stop button.

Here is an example of my code:

```
import Panel
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Panel.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.B_START.clicked.connect(self.StartBtnClicked)
        self.ui.B_STOP.clicked.connect(self.StopBtnClicked)

        #..
        #Other connect and function
        #..

    def StartBtnClicked(self):
        global Startbtn
        Startbtn = 1
        myClassA()

    def StopBtnClicked(self):
        global Startbtn
        Startbtn = 0


class myClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        print("myClassA")
        self.daemon = True
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while Startbtn == 1:
            print("DONE") 
            #Doing stuff
            time.sleep(0.2)
                           
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the UI to test it with:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(197, 310)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);\n""")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.B_START = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.B_START.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 71, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.B_START.setFont(font)
        self.B_START.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.B_START.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(65, 218, 78);\n""\n""\n""\n""")
        self.B_START.setObjectName("B_START")
        self.B_STOP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.B_STOP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 190, 71, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.B_STOP.setFont(font)
        self.B_STOP.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.B_STOP.setObjectName("B_STOP")
        self.B_SET = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.B_SET.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 71, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.B_SET.setFont(font)
        self.B_SET.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);\n""\n""border-width: 1px;\n""\n""")
        self.B_SET.setObjectName("B_SET")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 197, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.menubar.setFont(font)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menulk = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.menulk.setFont(font)
        self.menulk.setObjectName("menulk")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menulk.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Panel"))
        self.B_START.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
        self.B_STOP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "STOP"))
        self.B_SET.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET"))
        self.menulk.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "TEST"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You just have to put it in the same file and name the ui : "Pannel.py"
Is the solution i went with is the good one? If yes, why is main window is still crashing when I press Start.

Comment: Hi, I've added the UI. With that, I think everyone can run the program

Comment: change `self.run()` to `self.start()`

Comment: @eyllanesc Well, I would like to thank you. Sometime it's the simplest thing that we miss.  It's working now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would create a QObject and move it into a [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), in order to make it run in another thread, preventing the main thread to freeze:

```
import sys
import random
import string
import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QThread, QObject, QTimer


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

        layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start Thread 1')
        self.stopButton = QPushButton('Stop Thread 1')

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self._startThread)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self._stopThread)

        layout2.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout2.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        layout1.addLayout( layout2 )

        self.textArea = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.textArea.setPlaceholderText("")
        layout1.addWidget(self.textArea)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        # setup threads
        self._threads = []
        worker = Worker()
        self.wThread = QThread()
        self.wThread.setObjectName('worker')
        self._threads.append((self.wThread, worker))  # you need to keep track of the threads and instances.
        worker.moveToThread(self.wThread)
        worker.sendData.connect(self._showData)  # connect the signal from the thread to a function to to something with the data.
        self.wThread.started.connect(worker.start)

    def _showData(self, data):
        msg = f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] {data}"
        self.textArea.appendPlainText(msg)

    def _startThread(self):
        self.wThread.start()

    def _stopThread(self):
        self.wThread.quit()


class Worker(QObject):
    sendData = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(200)  # 200ms!
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.run)
        self.timer.start()

    def run(self):
        data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(24))
        self.sendData.emit(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see +- every 200ms a randomly generated string is sent back to the main window.