# How to stop a receiving QThread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I have a QThread object and I want to stop it from the main program but it gets stuck in the recv method.
Is there a way to stop the recv method when the close_worker function is called?

```
# Main function of the thread

    def handle:
        while self.run:
            data = sock.recv(data_size)
            self.intReady.emit(msg) 


# Stop the thread

def close_worker(self):
    self._mutex.lock()
    self.run = False
    self._mutex.unlock()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Threading a class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64934753/threading-a-class-in-python)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am not sure I understood how to make it works in my case beacuse I already use self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)  in order to call my thread and my problem is not that the gui freezes but that the thread is not dead until a message receives and I need it to get out the recv method without getting anything.

Comment: Assuming `sock` is from the socket of the standard library, you can use [`settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) and an internal flag (ie. `self.keepRunning`) that can be set from the main thread: if the condition is found, then just break the while loop.

Comment: @musicamante Can you explain me how to use a flag in the recv methos? and can I change this flag from an outer function and not only from the recv?

Comment: You don't have to put it in the recv method, but in the `run`. When you need to stop the thread, just use `self.someThread.keepRunning = False`.

Comment: @musicamante I do it but it works only after it get a message because it first gets stuck in the recv, then get a message and just then exit the loop because the keepRunning was set to False

Comment: As said, you must set a reasonable timeout for the socket, probably in the range of tens or hundreds of a second.